# Issue with npm and Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, npm

I am trying to install high-charts through npm and use it on the server side to output the data to a jade template. I am using basic express framework.

The first section in the link below is the guide that I am following.

*http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm*

However I am getting an error when I use this line of code

*require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);*

I have tried this across multiple computers and it's the same error across all.

[image]

Code used:

[image: Code used]

I have no idea why its failing. Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please can put the code you used into the body of your question, rather than a link to an image of it. Then if the link ever becomes dead we still have a useful question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use Highcharts on the server side, but that library requires DOM nodes from the client's HTML document to work (like the `document` object from the error you show and also the `container` where the chart will be drawn).

You can emulate the client side using PhantomJS. This way you can render your charts on the server.
You can try following [this guide](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside) from Highcharts documentation website.

However, it's definitely easier to load and use the library on the client side and use the server only to send the chart data to the client.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer and I will check it out. I am trying to create a node module that needs to extend highcharts so thats why I have to use the server side for. They should of made this clear in the documentation. Thanks again.